# Execute code at startup of angular application

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way I can execute some JavaScript code at start-up of my AngularJS application? I have some common code that I need to make sure runs before any of the app directives/controllers. I do not want to be tied to routes and `ng-view`, I need this to be a generic solution for any `ng-app`.

I thought I could use Module Config, and I actually tried that, but I am trying to call a service, which seems impossible to access on Module Load.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
    //.....
});
```

Comment: This gives me race conditions for calls into controllers. It seems that not all controllers are ready when the function executes.

Comment: @Dan ...yes, ha. i meant routes. i'm experiencing the same thing -- unexpected behavior where the resolve fns of controllers are executing before the app.run block.

Comment: I need to wait for an async $http call to complete (it fetches api key for tracking)

Answer (score 28):

## Short version

You need to use the `module.run(initializationFn)` function, where the actual method can depend on services. You can inject dependencies as per usual:

```
var app = angular
    .module('demoApp', [])
    .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.bodyClass = 'loading';
        // Etc. Initialize here.
    }]);
```

The example has initialization dependent on `$rootScope`, but you can also inject services, etc.

## Longer version

[The relevant `module.run` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run) is rather terse, as are the other (excellent) answers. Let me combine it into a more verbose example, that also shows how to inject a `factory` created service in your `initializationFn`:

```js
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

// Service that we'll also use in the .run method
app.factory('myService', [function() {
  var service = { currentItem: { started: new Date() } };
  
  service.restart = function() {
    service.currentItem.started = new Date();
  };
  
  return service;
}]);

// For demo purposes
app.controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.header = 'Demo!';
  $scope.item = myService.currentItem;
  $scope.restart = myService.restart;
}]);

// This is where your initialization code goes, which
// may depend on services declared on the module.
app.run(['$window', 'myService', function($window, myService) {
  myService.restart();
  $window.alert('Started!');
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller='demoCtrl' ng-cloak>
  <h1>{{ header }}</h1>
  <p>Current item started: {{ item.started }}</p>
  <p><button ng-click="restart()">Restart</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: is the longer version better and why ?

Comment: in the longer version can i use `this` instead of `service.`   ? and then not return anything ? would that work the same way ?

Comment: The longer version is just the longer version *of the explanation*. The mechanics of both versions are exactly the same.

Comment: If you're confused about the use of `this` in either scenario I suggest reading up in [e.g. this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/419956) and related work, and come back to SO with a specific problem/question if you're left with a problem (comments to another question are not really a good place to ask new questions).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "run" function from the Module API:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module

This code will be executed after injector creation so you should be able to get at the service you are looking to use.