# Problem inizialise a global variable AngularJS by calling a REST service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http, ecmascript-5

I want to create a global variable (**httpTimeout**) initialize at the start, contains a Long value returned by a synchrone call Rest Service and used it in different service

```
(
 function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('module')
.factory('MyService', function (
  $http,
  $q
 ){

var service = {};

var httpTimeout = function() {
      return $http({
          method: 'GET', '.../rest/getHttpTimeOut'
        }).then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return 30000;
        });
  };

 service.myService1= function (Model) {
    return $http({
      method: 'POST', '..../rest/callRestService1',
      data: Model, timeout : httpTimeout
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };

 service.myService2= function (Model) {
    return $http({
      method: 'POST', '..../rest/callRestService2',
      data: Model, timeout : httpTimeout
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };});
```

My rest service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getHttpTimeOut", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public long getHttpTimeOutValue() {
    return timeoutValue;
}
```

how i can retrieve this value globally (**httpTimeout**) for use in other services
Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello, if your question is how to do something on application start : 
[look at that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276095/execute-code-at-startup-of-angular-application)

After your application start you can use another service to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

if your question is how to do something on application start :
[look at that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276095/execute-code-at-startup-of-angular-application)

After your application start you can use another service to store the value.

Also if you want to apply this comportement for all request take a look to [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)